# How to set multiple output when build lib with vite

Tags: vuejs3, rollup, lib, vite

When I try to build a lib in vue3, I want to set multiple output file. Code like this:

```
rollupOptions {
  output: [
    {
      file: 'bundle.js',
      format: 'cjs'
    },
    {
      file: 'bundle.min.js',
      format: 'iife',
      name: 'version',
    }
  ]
}
```

Then I will get an error:

> You must set either "output.file" for a single-file build or "output.dir" when generating multiple chunks"

So, how should I do can make this work?

vite: 2.3.7

Answer (score 9):

You are missing the `input` config in `rollupOptions`.

The following **full vite config** example will generate a `index.bundle.[moduleFormat].js`
(you may need to adjust file path according to your setup)* :

```
import { defineConfig } from "vite";

// https://vitejs.dev/config/
export default (opts: { mode: "production" | "development"; command: "build" | "serve" }) => {
    return defineConfig({
        build: {
            target: "es2020",
            commonjsOptions: {
                sourceMap: false
            },
            rollupOptions: {
                input: {
                    index: "./src/index.js"
                },
                /* single
                output: {
                    format: "umd",
                    strict: false,
                    chunkFileNames: `[name].[hash].js`,
                    entryFileNames: "[name].bundle.umd.js",
                    dir: "dist"
                },
                */
                // array config example
                // from rollup: export type InternalModuleFormat = 'amd' | 'cjs' | 'es' | 'iife' | 'system' | 'umd';
                output: [
                    {
                        format: 'cjs',
                        entryFileNames: "[name].bundle.[format].js",
                    },
                    {
                        format: 'es',
                        entryFileNames: "[name].bundle.[format].js",
                    },
                    {
                        format: 'umd',
                        entryFileNames: "[name].bundle.[format].js",
                    },
                ]
            }
        }
    });
};
```

[image: result illustration]

To understand this answer better, please read the following sentence :

If you provide **an array of entry points** or **an object mapping names** to entry points, **they will be bundled to separate output chunks**.

And unless the `output.file` option is used, generated chunk names will follow the `output.entryFileNames` option. When using the object form, the `[name]` portion of the file name will be the name of the `object property` while for the array form, it will be the file name of the entry point.

Note that it is possible when using the object form to put entry points into different sub-folders by adding a `/` to the name.

If we follow the doc we can get more precisions and we know that :

```
output.dir
Type: string
Set in build.rollupOptions
```

Is for: The directory in which all generated chunks are placed and this option **is required** if **more than one chunk** is generated. Otherwise, the file option can be used instead.

```
output.file
Type: string
```

> The file to write to. **Can only be used if not more than one chunk is generated**.

Comment: sorry I do not follow this answer. the OP asks for an output array, not an object, to create different types of outputs (es, umd, cjs). How's that answer solve that? I am getting the same error as OP

Comment: @stilllife - you just have to define your config array `rollupOptions.output` and add the `rollupOptions.input` option as written in the answer, it's the key to not get an error (at least on `vite-2.3 to 2.8` when I wrote it). Check my edit.

Answer (score 2):

I guess that you're looking for [Library Mode](https://vitejs.dev/guide/build.html#library-mode)

And, see the [configuring Vite page](https://vitejs.dev/config/#build-lib) to tweak to your needs.